# How to add HTML button without the background "glitching"?

Tags: html, css

I want to implement a button in the center of screen that uses 2 triangles as background. The background on it's own works, but when `class="centerButton"` is added the output looks horrible(see example). I would like to know why the output is the way it is and how can I fix it. I tried to implement an image as a background, but that also didn't work as planned.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lgcotjv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `.box` as parent of `.centerButton`. And to make it in center, use `display: flex`

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.box {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ebca23;
}

.box:after {
    content: ' ';
    border-top: 100vh solid #d9d9d9;
    border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
    
.centerButton {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="centerButton">
      <button>Center screen button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having multiple elements and trying to center using a margin:

- Nest the button inside the `.box`
- Use `:before` instead of `:after` (so the background doesn't overlap the button, alternatively you could use `z-index`)
- You are already using absolute positioning for the background, so make use of that for positioning the button

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ebca23;
}

.box:before {
  content: ' ';
  border-top: 100vh solid #d9d9d9;
  border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.box button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <button>Center screen button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin is out of the div. That is why you are facing this issue. Instead of margin you should add padding to get the desired output :

```
.centerButton {
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this?

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.box {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ebca23;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box:after {
    content: ' ';
    border-top: 100vh solid #d9d9d9;
    border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
button {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <button>Center screen button</button>
</div>
```